# PyGame window stopped showing up

Tags: python, pygame

I've been learning python and decided to play around with PyGame. The PyGame window randomly stops showing up when I run the script. I don't get any errors or anything, the PyGame window just won't appear.

The scripts used to work, now they don't. I had this issue before and restarted my computer a few times and eventually it started working again. But it's happening again.

So, I've got no clue what's causing it and no clue how to fix it. I've tried it with two different PyGame scripts, neither work. I'll post a sample script below.

Im using:

- PyGame v2.0.1
- SDL v2.0.14
- Python 3.7.3
- OS: Windows 10
- IDE: PyCharm

I know PyGame version 2 is new, is this a bug with the new version? Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** restarting the computer once again fixed the issue in the short-term. I'm still looking for a long-term solution to the problem so I don't have to the restart the computer every time this happens.

Here's some sample code:

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
windowSize = sizeW, sizeH = 1920, 1080
window = pygame.display.set_mode(windowSize)
pygame.display.set_caption('Test')
black = 0, 0, 0
speed = 0.2
x, y = 50, 50
h, w = 50, 50
blue = 0, 0, 255

guy = pygame.image.load('tile032.png')

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x - speed > 0:
        x -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x + w + speed < sizeW:
        x += speed
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y - speed > 0:
        y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y + speed + h < sizeH:
        y += speed

    window.fill(black)
    window.blit(guy, (x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: http://inventwithpython.com/chapter16.html This explains pygame programming nicely. Hope this will helpful

Comment: Is `pygame.init()` just taking a long time? That's a known problem which you should be able to find existing solutions for. Have you verified that the code after that point is actually running?

Comment: Do you get a black screen when you run the script?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to be using either `pygame.quit()` or just `quit()` or say run is False than using `sys.exit()` because for me personally it just broke my code while running it with pygame. So try out this for killing your pygame window:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        # loop will run for last time then the game will stop
        run = False
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Calling `pygame.quit()` is important, because it allows all the allocated resources to be properly shutdown and released.  Maybe you've run out of file handles, audio resources, font handles or suchlike by not cleaning up. Perhaps this is preventing the window from opening again.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the closing window properly , use pygame.quit().

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: This didn't fix it, unfortunately. The issue is with having the window pop up, not with closing the window.

Comment: Try adding clock.tick()

Comment: I restarted my computer which fixed the issue. I don't think adding clock.tick() would fix it in the future, that's already in one of the other programs that faces the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually comes when you are exiting pygame window just after calling it. It can be resolved by exiting the pygame only after the run variable goes as False. Either make the logic when your program ends or after the run function is defined as false.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case here. I've run the script and let it sit for a couple of minutes to see if the PyGame window will eventually pop up. Still nothing. Even when I added pygame.quit() to this script, as someone else suggested. So I don't think quitting too early is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the Pygame window closes, look at the terminal to see if there is an error. If you don't use Linux, look at the place where the error usually comes up.

Comment: Its already mentioned in the question, that there is no error that can be observed being displayed when the window stops being visible. This could've been a comment

Answer (score 0):

How I usually do it is have `pygame.quit()` at the very end of the code, outside of every loop, class, and method. I don't usually use `sys.exit()` since I am a very new pygame user, but you should also set `run` to false in the event loop so then it hits that `pygame.quit()` method at the end. And like others suggest, maybe have `sys.exit()` after that too.

Comment: Warren Sande has a really nice version of this that I use with all my pygame scripts.   `running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.get_event():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
pygame.quit()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sys.exit()`, use `pygame.quit()`. I think that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add some print statements at different points of the code so you can see if it gets stuck and where. This would help a lot with troubleshooting.

I know it is unrelated ,but when using `pygame.image.load()` you should add `.convert()` to the end (or `.convert_alpha()` if the image contains transparent spots).

E.g. `guy = pygame.image.load("tile032.png").convert_alpha()`

I'm sorry i couldn't help more.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks, error in your code here

> window.blit(guy, (x, y))

In pygame, as I know, you have to use pygame.Rect, but not slices. Try this code

```
window.blit(guy, guy.get_rect(topleft=(x, y)))
```

*https://younglinux.info/pygame/image*.

And, I think you should do this

```
import pygame, sys, time # code remade
pygame.init()
windowSize = sizeW, sizeH = 1920, 1080
window = pygame.display.set_mode(windowSize)
pygame.display.set_caption('Test')
black = 0, 0, 0
speed = 0.2
x, y = 50, 50
h, w = 50, 50
blue = 0, 0, 255

guy = pygame.image.load('tile032.png')

deltaTime = 0 #code remade

run = True
while run:
    start = time.time()#code remade
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x - speed > 0:
        x -= speed * deltaTime #code remade
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x + w + speed < sizeW:
        x += speed * deltaTime #code remade
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y - speed > 0:
        y -= speed * deltaTime #code remade
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y + speed + h < sizeH:
        y += speed * deltaTime #code remade

    window.fill(black)
    window.blit(guy, guy.get_rect(topleft=(x, y)))
    pygame.display.update()
    deltaTime = time.time() - start #code remade
```